# Not sure why Python readlines() doesn't work here

Tags: python-2.7, readline

Hi I have a block of code here, intending to read the input into variables:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readlines().split()))
    n, capacity = data[0:2]
    values = data[2:(2 * n + 2):2]
    weights = data[3:(2 * n + 2):2]
    opt_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values)
    print("{:.10f}".format(opt_value))
```

Then the self-defined get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values) will be executed. Input example:

```
3 50
60 20
100 50
120 30
```

It is supposed to achieve the following:

```
n = 3
capacity = 50
values = [60,100,120]
weights = [20,50,30]
```

However, the code doesn't proceed after I type in the above input numbers and gives me no result. That means the numbers are not read into the variables and lists are not formulated. I tried my code into an automated error checker; it tells me:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Why is this and how should I modify my code?

Additional question: does the number reading automatically knows where to stop, i.e. when it detects space and no following numbers? I assume the code will execute the function and calculate the result right after it reads all the input data, is that correct in terms of process? I feel like lacking a 'step' to notify the code to 'calculate' after typing in the inputs.

Comment: `readlines()` returns a list of strings (one string per line). You could change that to `read()`, which reads the entire file into a single string, which then can be split with `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` returns `list` which doesn't have method `split` (it is a method of `str` object which represents a single line), so your code is equivalent to this:

```
l = sys.stdin.readlines()   # ["0 1\n", "2 3\n"]
l.split()
```

If you wish to apply `split()` to each line, you should add another `map` call our use list or generator comprehension, i.e.

```
data = list(map(int, map(lambda line: line.split(), sys.stdin.readlines()))
data = list(map(int, line.split() for line in sys.stdin.readlines()))
```

Or use foreach:

```
data = []
for line in sys.stdin:
     data.append(map(int, line.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` returns a list of strings, and `split()` is only defined for strings. If you want return the input as a list of list with two ints each, you must apply to the elements of the list:

```
[map(int, x.split(" ")) for x in sys.stdin.readlines().split()]
```